# How to reduce the height and text padding of a bootstrap breadcrumb?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to know how to reduce the height and the vertical padding between the text and the box borders of a standard Bootstrap breadcrumb:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Home</li>
</ol>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Library</li>
</ol>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data</li>
</ol>
```

**Original:**
[image]

**What I need:** (reduce the tickness of the bar and the spacing between the text and the bar upper and lower borders. Ths font remains the same size)

[image]

Comment: Why the downvotes ?

Comment: Check the bootstrap stylesheet and edit the padding there or add `.breadcrumb` to your stylesheet, edit the components and make `!important`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting padding in `.breadcrumb` class by override the bootstrap css

```css
.breadcrumb {
    padding: 2px 15px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Home</li>
</ol>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Library</li>
</ol>
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Library</a></li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Data</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

change the padding

CODE:

```
.breadcrumb {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
 }
```

EXAMPLE: https://jsfiddle.net/a2v66hrh/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your custom CSS file for example:

```
.breadcrumb {
   padding: 4px 15px;
}
```

Bootstrap defines a top and bottom padding of 8pk. Just use any lower value than this.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below css

```
.breadcrumb {
    padding:1px 15px !important;
 }
```